# 1611 era past tenses

Tags: tenses, past-tense

King James era third person singular present tense verbs ended in -th or -eth. How was the related past tense formed? Just read a para in a work of Jane Austen fan fiction wherein all the verbs were in past tense except for the allusion "my cup runneth over," jarringly present and unparallel.

Answer (score 2):

In Early Modern English, only the second-person singular with *thou* is inflected for person or number, using the same *-st* suffix as the second-person singular present, except with the verb *BE*:

> I came, thou camest, he came, we came, you came, they came
> I was, thou wert, he was, we were, you were, they were

As for *my cup runneth over* that's a quotation from the 23rd psalm in the AV:

> The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want.
>
> He maketh me to lie down in green pastures: he leadeth me beside the still waters.
>
> He restoreth my soul: he leadeth me in the paths of righteousness for his name's sake.
>
> Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil: for thou art with me; thy rod and thy staff they comfort me.
>
> Thou preparest a table before me in the presence of mine enemies: thou anointest my head with oil; **my cup runneth over**.
>
> Surely goodness and mercy shall follow me all the days of my life: and I will dwell in the house of the Lord for ever.

It's something of a fixed phrase for "I am fully content"; I don't think anybody would quote it casually in any modernized form.